# How do I set the mysql server character set in FreeBSD 8.2?

Tags: freebsd, mysql, character-encoding

My mysql server's current server character set is `latin1`.  My server is started on startup via rc.conf setting `mysql_enable="YES"`.  How to set my server to use `utf8` as the server character set?

Answer (score 3):

I edited /etc/rc.conf and added the mysql_args line below:

```
mysql_enable="YES"
mysql_args="--character-set-server=utf8"
```

This works and I can see the server character set is updated.

Comment: I'd prefer a config file based solution but this is working for now

Answer (score 2):

From the manual,

> Specify character settings at server startup. To select a character set and collation at server startup, use the --character-set-server and --collation-server options.

You include the following in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

(You could find samples of my.cnf in `/usr/local/share/mysql`)

[More information on mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-applications.html)

Comment: /etc/mysql doesn't exist on FreeBSD

Comment: @User that's a mistake, sorry. answer updated

Comment: I'm trying this but for some reason mysql doesn't want to start when the file is there.  If I rename the file then mysql starts fine.